# Select Query Error

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I want to create a login account  by matching UserName & Password. I want to save the result in a local variable named as result. When a user logs in, the result should be one, but it always returning -1. My code is following......

```
    protected void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Name = nameTextBox.Text;
        string Password = passwordTextBox.Text;
        nameTextBox.Text = "";
        passwordTextBox.Text = "";
        string connectionstring = @"Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=HMIS;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        connection.Open();
        string selectquery = "Select ID from  UsersInfo where UserName='" + @Name+ "' and Password='" + @Password + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectquery, connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
         //object result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //if (result != null)
        int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (result > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter name was incorrect @UserName whereas in the query string @Name was used.

Try this code.

```
protected void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Name = nameTextBox.Text;
    string Password = passwordTextBox.Text;
    nameTextBox.Text = "";
    passwordTextBox.Text = "";
    string connectionstring = @"Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=HMIS;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    connection.Open();
    string selectquery = "Select ID from  UsersInfo where UserName='" + @Name+ "' and Password='" + @Password + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectquery, connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
     //object result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //if (result != null)
    int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (result > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The ExecuteNonQuery Method returns the number of row(s) affected by either an INSERT, an UPDATE or a DELETE. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.

Use the ExecuteReader method instead. This returns a SqlDataReader, which has a HasRows property.
ExecuteNonQuery shouldn't be used for SELECT statements.